# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to System.Data.DataTable'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: c#, linq, data-entry

I am trying to create a Data Table using my Entity Framework with this code

```
private DataTable dtSubjects
    {
        get
        {
            object obj = this.Session["Subjects"];
            if ((!(obj == null)))
            {
                return ((DataTable)(obj));
            }
            DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
            myDataTable = from r in DbContext.Subjects
                          where r.LinkAnalysisId == LinkID
                          select r;

            this.Session["Subjects"] = myDataTable;
            return myDataTable;
        }
    }
```

However I get this  error.
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable to System.Data.DataTable'. An explicit conversion exists

I have tried casting to a list but that does not work.  Can someone please shed some light on this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Doing a `new` followed immediately by the query is pointless. You are overwriting the object just created.

Comment: Why do you want to create a loosely typed `DataTable` if you already have a strongly typed `IQueryable<Subject>`? I would create a `List<Subject>` with `ToList` and return that. If you insist on a `DataTable` you have to use a loop to fill it.

Comment: Your comment made a lot of sense So I have abandoned the DataTable path and have added the IQueryable to my  project.  with this code.

Comment: Sorry could not add code to a comment.  Will try as you suggested and see what develops.  Thanks for you input

Answer (score 0):

You need to include System.Data.DataSetExtensions in your project and use the CopyToDataTable extension method:

```
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataTable = (from r in DbContext.Subjects
                      where r.LinkAnalysisId == LinkID
                      select r).CopyToDataTable();
```

<strike>EDIT: Add ToList after the query which is IEnumerable.</strike>

EDIT 2: See this SO entry on converting an object to a DataRow.  The collection of DataRows can then be copied into the DataTable.  [Converting class object to datarow using LINQ in vb.net.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016465/converting-class-object-to-datarow-using-linq-in-vb-net)

Comment: `DbContext.Subjects` is not an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Your _edit_ doesn't help either. Entity framework is not a `DataSet`. OP's requirement is weird.

Comment: @TheSharpNinja `IQueryable` extends `IEnumerable`, so `DbContext.Subjects` *is* an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score -2):

Try adding FirstorDefault(); or First(); at the end of your select clause.

something like:

```
        DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
        myDataTable = (from r in DbContext.Subjects
                      where r.LinkAnalysisId == LinkID
                      select r).FirstorDefault();
```

Let me know if it works.